# How to remove suffix from string?

Tags: javascript

How can I remove the following suffix:

1. px
2. %
3. em

from some string if it contains that suffix ?
Like enter I get string which can be measure of width of div and that can ends with 'px', '%', 'em' and can also be without, so I need to remove suffix if it exists.

Comment: You actually need to get the numeric part...

Comment: @Damir, if this problem was solved consider to accept an answer

Answer (score 7):

```
var s = "34em";
parseInt(s, 10); // returns 34
```

this works for `em, px, %, pt`... and any other suffix even if it has a space before.

Use `parseFloat()` instead if you have non-integer values

```
var s = "81.56%";
parseFloat(s); // returns 81.56
```

Comment: What about digits after decimal point: `parseInt("10.4%",10)`?

Answer (score -1):

You can use a regular expression to get a string with only the digits:

```
var s = input.replace(/\D+/g, '');
```

You can parse the string as a number, that will ignore the non-numeric characters at the end:

```
var n = parseInt(input, 10);
```